# Can't update dialog node in watson conversation service via node-red

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, watson-conversation

In node-red in ibm cloud. I am able to use the IBM Watson node "assistant workspace manager" to retrieve a particular dialog node. However, I am unable to use the same "assistant workspace manager" to update a dialog node. I keep getting the error message "Invalid Request Body".

It is not a matter of incorrect credentials, because I use the same credentials for both instances.

Below is the code in my functions module that passes the information to my "assistant workspace manager" node so that it can update a dialog node in my watson conversation workspace.

```
var uptime = msg.payload[1].d.uptime;
var message = "Server uptime is " + uptime + " seconds.";
msg.topic = "";
msg.dialog_node.output.generic[0].values[0].text = message;
msg.payload = msg.dialog_node;
return msg;
```

I literally took the dialog node that was returned to me and combined it with the message that had the info I wanted to inject, then modified the payload (before attempting to update my dialog node) so that the payload looked exactly like the dialog node that was returned to me (except with the text for the message modified).

I have successfully done this in the past, by manually formatting the msg.payload object similar to the format that it is returned in. I tried that also, but when that didn't work, I attempted this method.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: may be you could pass the msg in a debug node to see what are the properties of this msg and then change/set the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the underlying Node.JS SDK for watson-developer-cloud has been updated. https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant?code=node#update-dialog-node

The JSON that you supply needs to have at least one field with a `new_` prefix as a key.

So in this example the condition is being updated:

```
{
  "type":"standard",
  "title":"Entry Point For Up Down Commands",
  "output":{},
  "context":
    {
      "appl_action":"increase"
    },
  "next_step":
    {
      "behavior":"jump_to",
      "selector":"condition",
      "dialog_node":"node_11_1467233013716"
    },
  "new_conditions":"#turn_up",
  "dialog_node":"Entry Point For Up Down Commands",
  "previous_sibling":"node_1_1487022155950"
}
```

I need to amend the node info tab with this information.

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman. Thanks so much for the quick response. This is the correct answer. For my question, I simply had to change: "output" to "new_output" since that is what I wanted to update. Instead of pulling from the dialog_node that was returned to me, I simply manually built the json in my function.